# cin.getline() equivalent when getting a char from a function.

Tags: c++, arrays, char

From what I understand cin.getLine gets the first char(which I think it a pointer) and then gets that the length.  I have used it when cin for a char.  I have a function that is returning a pointer to the first char in an array.  Is there an equivalent to get the rest of the array into a char that I can use the entire array.  I explained below what I am trying to do.  The function works fine, but if it would help I could post the function.

```
cmd_str[0]=infile();// get the pointer from a function
cout<<"pp1>";
cout<< "test1"<<endl;
//  cin.getline(cmd_str,500);something like this with the array from the function                                                   
cout<<cmd_str<<endl; this would print out the entire array
cout<<"test2"<<endl;
length=0;
length= shell(cmd_str);// so I could pass it to this function
```

Comment: The first char is not a pointer. No char is a pointer. Please post the rest of the code so we can actually run it. Also please describe what is wrong and/or what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: It's very much not clear either what you're trying to do or what you're asking. getline reads at most n-1 characters, or until it hits a newline. It doesn't tell you how many characters it actually read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if `cmd_str` is an array of `char` and `infile` returns a pointer to a string, that first assignment will give you an error. It tries to assign a pointer to a single char.

What you seem to want is `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(cmd_str, infile() ARRAY_LENGTH - 1);
cmd_str[ARRAY_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';
```

I make sure to add the string terminator to the array, because if `strncpy` copies all `ARRAY_LENGTH - 1` characters, it will *not* append the terminator.

If `cmd_str` is a proper array (i.e. declared like `char cmd_str[ARRAY_LENGTH];`) then you can use `sizeof(cmd_str) - 1` instead of `ARRAY_LENGTH - 1` in my example. However, if `cmd_str` is passed as a pointer to a function, this will not work.

Comment: Y u use `MAGIC_NUMBER` codes and unsafe C string handling functions?

Comment: @DeadMG Using `MAGIC_NUMBER` is much better than using something like a _real_ magic number, like `64`. I also added a paragraph that `sizeof` may be used, but only in certain cases. And I explicitly terminate the string, making the copying safe, and also explain why.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string stream:

```
char const * p = get_data();  // assume null-terminated

std::istringstream iss(std::string(p));

for (std::string line; std::getline(iss, line); )
{
    // process "line"
}
```

If the character array is not null-terminated but has a given size `N`, say `std::string(p, N)` instead.